# OS 4.0 features in backwards compatible app

Tags: iphone, ios4, eventkit

I have an OS 4 app that was completely compatible with 3.x up until I added eventkit. Is there a way I can omit this feature if they are on a 3.x device? I have

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 40000
...code
#endif
```

around my stuff but it seems to be failing on initial launch and I am thinking due to the linking of the EventKit.framework. The only error i am getting is the super descriptive

```
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Cannot call into the loader at present, it is locked.)
```

and if i remove this framework and comment out my eventkit code, it all works fine. Is there no way to prevent the linking of newer frameworks for older OS'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should weak-link EventKit. Open your target, find EventKit under Linked Libraries, and change its type from Required to Weak.

Comment: perfect. I knew i saw something somewhere. Just couldn't re-find it. Thanks!